# Sending data scraped with BS4 to sqlite3 database using Python

Tags: python, sqlite, beautifulsoup

I am scraping the names of cafes in different neighbourhoods and want to add them to an SQLite3 table within a database. However all that is being added to the table is the variable `cafeNames` not the actual list of cafe names.

I have been searching through the SQLite and BS4 documentation and following a whole host of tutorials but I can't seem to figure it out. I'd be grateful for some guidance.

Get cafe names code

```
import requests
import sqlite3

def cafenames():
    url = 'https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-thornbury'
    response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)

    soup_cafe_names = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    type(soup_cafe_names)

    cafeNames = soup_cafe_names.findAll('h2', attrs={"class":"venue-title", })
    cafeNames = [ul.text.encode for ul in cafeNames]
```

Connect to DB code

```
    try:
        sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('anybody_database.db')
        cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
        print("Database created and Successfully Connected to anybody_database")

        sqlite_select_Query = "select sqlite_version();"
        cursor.execute(sqlite_select_Query)
        record = cursor.fetchall()
        print("SQLite Database Version is: ", record)
        cursor.close()

    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Error while connecting to sqlite", error)

    finally:
        if (sqliteConnection):
            sqliteConnection.close()
            print("The SQLite connection is closed")
```

Create Table Code

```
    try:
        sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('anybody_database.db')
        sqlite_create_table_query = ''' CREATE TABLE cafes (
                                        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                                        name TEXT NOT NULL);'''
        cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
        print("Successfully Connected to SQLite")
        cursor.execute(sqlite_create_table_query)
        sqliteConnection.commit()
        print("SQLite table created")

        cursor.close()

    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Error while creating a sqlite table", error)
    finally:
        if (sqliteConnection):
            sqliteConnection.close()
            print("sqlite connection is closed")
```

Add the cafe names to the table code:

```
def insertVariableIntoTable(name):
    try:
        sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('anybody_database.db')
        cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
        print("Successfully Connected to SQLite")

        sqlite_insert_with_param = """INSERT INTO cafes
                            (name)
                            VALUES
                            (?)"""

        data_tuple = (name)
        cursor.execute(sqlite_insert_with_param, data_tuple)
        sqliteConnection.commit()
        print("Python Variables inserted successfully into cafes table ")

        cursor.close()


    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Failed to insert data into sqlite table", error)
    finally:
        if (sqliteConnection):
            sqliteConnection.close()
            print("The SQLite connection is closed")

insertVariableIntoTable('cafeNames')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your beautifulSoup extraction.

```
def cafenames():
    url = 'https://www.broadsheet.com.au/melbourne/guides/best-cafes-thornbury'
    response = requests.get(url, timeout=5)

    soup_cafe_names = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    type(soup_cafe_names)

    cafeNames = soup_cafe_names.findAll('h2', attrs={"class":"venue-title", })
    cafeNames = [ul.text.strip().encode() for ul in cafeNames]
```

`encode` is a method not an attribute. So the output from this function is as follows

```
[b'Prior',
 b'Rat the Cafe',
 b'Ampersand Coffee and Food',
 b'Umberto Espresso Bar',
 b'Brother Alec',
 b'Short Round',
 b'Jerry Joy',
 b'The Old Milk Bar',
 b'Little Henri',
 b'Northern Soul']
```

I would rather not encourage encode unless it's for a reason

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help out. Can I ask why you wouldn't encourage encode. It may be redundant for what I am trying to achieve, but it worked on that code block before I started figuring out the database stuff, may not be necessary anymore...

Comment: Here you go - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58182188/why-do-we-need-to-encode-and-decode-in-python

Comment: If this has answered your question, upvote and accept the answer

Comment: Unfortunately all that is still going into the table is 'cafeNames' :(  not the names above. Sorry work started and COVID19 is causing a lot of headaches so my reply is slow.